# Determine if a UL has 1 or more LI within

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use JavaScript to determine if a UL contains 1 or more LI's within?

Pseudo code

```
if('ul#items' has >= 1 LI){
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 39, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$('ul#items li').length >= 1
```

Without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById('items').getElementsByTagName('li').length >= 1
```

Comment: Or just simplify with `> 0`.

Answer (score 5):

With jQuery:

```
if( $('#items li').length >= 1 ){...
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `document.getElementById("items").childNodes.length` and a number comparison operator. If your `ul` does contain other nodes than `li`, you will have to filter them.

In jQuery:

```
 $("#items").children("li").length
```

I guess you only want direct children, so don't use find().

Comment: A UL can also have text nodes as children so `childNodes.length` is not a good option. You could use `getElementsByTagName('li')` though.

Comment: That depends on the document. If the `li`s were dynamically added, there won't be text nodes. But if your list contains other lists, `getElementsByTagName` is wrong as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($('ul#items').children('li').length) {
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$('ul#items li').length
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery

```
if($('ul > li').size()>0) {

}
```

That will check that the UL element has more than 0 direct child li elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('ul#items > li').length >= 1)
```